# namespace validity in c++

Tags: c++, namespaces

I have a simple question for namespace in C++. There are errors when I compiling the following little piece of code. I don't understand why. Thanks for any help in advance!

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int x=100;

namespace first
{
     int x=1;
}
namespace second
{
     int x=2;
}

int main(){

     {
        using namespace first;
        cout<<x<<endl;
     }

     {
        using namespace second;
        cout<<x<<endl;
     }

     cout<<x<<endl;
}
```

If I comment out the x declared in the global scope and the last statement. It works fine. But in my mind, the first x is declared in the std namespace and using namespace first and second in the main will be invalid after the the code block they are declared(so the namespace will be std again). So the above code should work. Where am I wrong?

Comment: Are you actually getting any errors or does it just not make sense to you? Please edit your question to indicate this, as it contradicts itself. See: `There are errors when I compiling` and `It works fine`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But in my mind, the first x is declared in the std namespace

Your mind is wrong.  The `using namespace std` makes names from `std` available in the global namespace, it doesn't mean names declared in the global namespace are in `std`.

`x` is declared in the global namespace.

> so the namespace will be std again

No, nothing in your file is in namespace `std`, only the contents of `<iostream>` are in namespace `std`.

The error is that when you try to use `x` there are two different variables in scope, `::x` and `first::x` that you could be referring to, so it is ambiguous.  You can disambiguate with a using declaration instead of a using directive:

```
 {
    using first::x;
    cout<<x<<endl;
 }
```

This says that in that scope `x` refers to `first::x`

Comment: one more question please: can we using multiple namespace? If not, why can we still using cout without using qualifier after using the first namespace?

Comment: last one: what will be the namespace after the last code block(which contains using namespace second)? The namespace will be back to std, right?

Comment: First question: You can use `using` for multiple namespaces, but if they declare the same names then you can get ambiguities. Second question: No, you are confused. Nothing in your file is in namespace `std`, that code is not "in" namespace `std`. Saying `using namespace std` does **not** put you _in_ that namespace, it allows you to use names from that namespace. After the `using namespace std` you can always see the names from that namespace, the `using namespace second` does not "go into" that namespace, and so you do not "go back" to namespace `std`, you were never in namespace `std`

Comment: After the last code block you are in default namespace **not** in the std. But you can use the properties which are in **std**

Comment: first question: if using two namespaces, both names in the two namespaces will be seen in my file? Second question: I understand what you mean now. What I am wondering is: since using namespace std is declared in the global scope, so the names in std will always be seen in my file. But for the first and second namespace, after the block where they are declared, names in these namespace will not be seen again. am i right?

Comment: 1) yes, that's the problem with the code in your original question: two variables called `x` are seen and the compiler doesn't know if you mean `::x` or `first::x`. 2) yes, the `using namespace first` and `using namespace second` have no effect after the end of the block that contains them

Comment: @user3068966 You are already `using` multiple namespaces. For example, cout is in `std` whilst your `x`'s are in their `first` and `second` namespaces.

Comment: @JonathanWakely I thought the 'most local' variable (i.e. the one closest to local scope) `shadowed` the other?

Comment: @OMGtechy, I don't know what you mean by closest, or "most local", or which of my statements (if any) you're referring to

Comment: @JonathanWakely  `int main {int x = 0; {int x = 5; std::cout << x; } }` would print 5, as it has the most local scope and shadows the first x.

Comment: @OMGtechy, yes, that's true, but doesn't apply to the OP's question as there are no declarations of `x` in the inner scope, a using-directive is not a declaration of `x`. That's why my answer says you can use `using first::x;` instead.

Answer (score 2):

in this case x variable is ambiguous. The compiler can't find which x you are going to use. You can write like this.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int x=100;

namespace first
{
     int x=1;
}
namespace second
{
     int x=2;
}

int main(){

     {
        cout<<first::x<<endl;
     }

     {
        cout<<second::x<<endl;
     }

     cout<<x<<endl;
}
```

now your code will compile.

Answer (score 0):

The first x is not in the std namespace.  It would only be in the std namespace if defined like this:

```
namespace std
{
    int x;
}
```

Because it's not in that namespace, it's matched by references to x later in the program, and such references become ambiguous when another namespace declaring x is also being used (as in using namespace first / second).